# Change the link on a sitemap based on if a user is logged in?

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, aspmenu

I have a sitemap that has a link for when a user is not logged in, but when they do login, the link should change, for example, nonmember.aspx should change to member.aspx.  This sitemap is tied to an asp:menu.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to have two nodes in your sitemap.

1. One node shows up for **Anonymous** users.
2. One node shows up for **Authenticated** users with the security access

I believe you can set this up quite simply.

The end result is the same as changing the link but it's easier to maintain.

To add to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode title="Home" url="~/" roles="*">
        <siteMapNode url="~/Member.aspx" title="Home" roles="SpecialPeople" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/Nonmember.aspx" title="Site Map" roles="HideForUsers" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

So, you set up a rule that denies access to the "`HideForMembers`" role to authenticated users. It's something like that. ASP.NET will take the first rule it finds a match, so you should be able to accomplish it this way.

Otherwise, you could do a `Menu_OnDataBound` and look for the node:

```
Protected Sub menMainDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Try

        Dim myPage As New Page
        Dim myPrincipal As IPrincipal
        Dim colNodes As New Collection

        myPrincipal = myPage.User

        If myPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated = True Then

                Dim menNode As MenuItem

                For Each menNode In menMain.Items

                    Select Case menNode.Value.ToString
                        Case "Products"
                            colNodes.Add(menNode)
                        Case "Contact Us"
                            colNodes.Add(menNode)
                        Case "About Us"
                            colNodes.Add(menNode)
                        Case "Links"
                            colNodes.Add(menNode)
                    End Select

                Next

                For Each menNode In colNodes
                    menMain.Items.Remove(menNode)
                Next

         End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

[source](http://forums.asp.net/p/1161879/1922913.aspx#1922913)

Comment: Not an example, but here's another approach:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1161879/1922913.aspx#1922913

Comment: This works, but Nonmember and member are pretty much the same page, so if a member logs in, they will see both.  Do you know if there is a way to hide the nonmember page to members, so they will not see duplicates?

Comment: Sure, you should be able to set a rule to "Deny" access to logged in users.

Comment: I actually ended up using the web.config instead of the sitemap. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

The below is the web.config code you're looking for:

```
<location path="Registration.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```